# c# udp broadcast package not receiving

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

I got into UDP and decided to make a small chat just for practice.
I ran into a problem and I can't figure it out myself.

I created two c# console Programs which are exactly the same (Just Port is different)

I send a UDP broadcast package and then want to receive it on the second console program. What happens tho is that the program I send the broadcast from receives it and the other program doesn't. Same happens at the other way round.

I already switched off my firewall --> doesn't change anything.

I post you the whole code, I hope you guys can help me I would really love to keep going! Thank you so much!

```
class Program
{
    const int PORT = 10101;
    private static readonly UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient(PORT);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        udpclient.EnableBroadcast = true;
        //bool for calling async receiver just once
        bool receiving = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Chat 2");
        //to keep while loop running --> change later
        bool keepchatting = true;
        #region keepchating loop
        while (keepchatting)
        {
            if (!receiving)
            {
                startlistening();
            }
            receiving = true;
            newmessage();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //new message --> call sendmessage to broadcast text via UDP
    public static void newmessage()
    {
        string msg;
        msg = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        sendmessage(message);
    }

    //Broadcast text via UDP
    public static void sendmessage(byte[] tosend)
    {
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        client.EnableBroadcast = true;
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), PORT);
        client.Send(tosend, tosend.Length, ip);
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Sent!");
    }

    static IAsyncResult ar = null;
    //Setup Async Receive Method 
    public static void startlistening()
    {
        ar = udpclient.BeginReceive(RecievedMessage, new object());
    }

    //Message
    public static void RecievedMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
        byte[] bytes = udpclient.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: " + msg);
        startlistening();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try broadcast using a multicast IP 224-239.  The braodcast IP 255.255.255.255 is reserved for certain protocols.  I've never been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed only two parts to your code, on each client set the remote port number of the other client, try this:

On one client:

```
const int PORT = 10101;
const int PORT_Remote = 10102;

IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), PORT_Remote);
```

On the other client:

```
const int PORT = 10102;
const int PORT_Remote = 10101;

IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), PORT_Remote);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote an application recently where I was sending socket messages back and forth between two applications on my laptop.  I used 127.0.0.1 (default IP address for local host) for the IP address. Could you try that?

Comment: Still, doesn't work, but thank you anyway, is my code alright or is there some mistake probably ?

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, but believe me when I say that I am a novice.  I've got a working UDP client that I made for another application that does not include the IP address in the client.Send() signature.  Also, I never close the client.  My understanding is that there is no handshaking with UDP the way there is for TCP.